# Составить LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Добрый день. Прошу вашей помощи в написание LINQ-запроса.

Допустим, у нас 3 поля: категория, продавец, количество.

Исходная таблица:

```
Категория  Продавец  Количество
--------------------------------
  200       Пупкин      50
  400       Иванов      150
  200       Пупкин      100
  300       Пупкин      355
  400       Иванов      500
```

Итоговая таблица:

```
Категория  Продавец  Количество
--------------------------------
  200       Пупкин      150
  400       Иванов      650
  300       Пупкин      355
```

Нужно сгруппировать по категории, потом по продавцу и посчитать сумму количества. Как это сделать на LINQ в C#? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var items = new[] 
        {
            new { Category = 200, Seller = "Пупкин", Count = 50 },
            new { Category = 400, Seller = "Иванов", Count = 150 },
            new { Category = 200, Seller = "Пупкин", Count = 100 },
            new { Category = 300, Seller = "Пупкин", Count = 355 },
            new { Category = 400, Seller = "Иванов", Count = 500 },
        };

var gr = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Category, x.Seller });

foreach (var g in gr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"{0} {1} {2}", g.Key.Category, g.Key.Seller, 
                                      g.Sum(x => x.Count));
}
```

Comment: ... ну или просто

    .Select(g => new { g.Key.Category, g.Key.Seller, Total = g.Sum(x => x.Count) })

Comment: @VladD тоже вариант, впрочем, с GroupBy будет нагляднее

Comment: @DreamChild: Я имел в виду, после `GroupBy`.

Comment: @VladD а черт, затупил)

Comment: @DreamChild @VladD спасибо! Всё работает! Как раз встрял на .Select(), а тут и с foreah и с select пример.